# javascript variable shows in console.log but not in browser output

Tags: javascript, hashchange, window-object

I am trying to reuse the output of the year variable. 
I will need to reuse the updated value [based on hashchange] in multiple functions later on.
It displays the correct value in the browser console, but it doesn't display in the browser.

```
<html>
<body>
<p></p>
<a href="#2018-01">1</a>
<a href="#2018-02">2</a>
</body>
<script>
location.hash = '#2019';
showHash();
var p = document.querySelector('p');
p.innerHTML = window.year;

function showHash() {
  return year = location.hash;  
}
window.onhashchange = showHash;
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `year` is not a reference to something; it is a primitive value, so when you *copy* it to `p.innerHTML` it does not matter what happens to `year` afterwards -- that `innerHTML` will not update. You should just do `p.innerHTML = year` *inside* `showHash`.

Comment: You're also calling a function before it has been initialised

Comment: @SuperDJ Declarations are hoisted in JS. It doesn’t matter.

Comment: @trincot, what is a primitive value? I know it works inside the hash function, I just want to be able to reuse the return value in other functions later. I don't want to stick all the functions inside showHash()

Comment: See my answer. See also [primitive value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assigning `location.hash` to `year` you are not modifying `p.innerHTML`. `year` and `p.innerHTML` are not referencing each other's value. When you initialised as follows:

```
p.innerHTML = window.year;
```

The value of `year` was *copied* so now you have two values which happen to be the same at that moment, but they are not linked so that if you would assign a new value to the one, it would also update the other. No, they are not references.

So in the event handler you should also assign the new hash to `p.innerHTML`, or better -- as the hash is text -- assign it to `p.textContent`:

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p');
var year;

function showHash() {
  // Assign both to textContent and year (they are independent)
  p.textContent = year = location.hash;
  // Maybe call some other functions which need to know about `year`
  manage();
}

function manage() {
  console.log(year);
  // ... etc
}

window.onhashchange = showHash;

location.hash = '#2019'; // This triggers showHash, no need to call it explicitly
```

```html
<p></p>
<a href="#2018-01">1</a>
<a href="#2018-02">2</a>
```

Comment: I still don't understand how to access the year variable outside the function

Comment: Like if I do something like this:for (var i = 0; i < year.substring(4,5); i++) { console.log(i); } i get year is undefined in the console log

Comment: Well it has an undefined value *before* the first time the event triggers. You must call your further actions from within that handler.

Comment: so everything has to be inside the showHash function that needs to access the year variable?

Comment: Yes, but you can of course call another function from there, so you can spread code over different functions. I added some code to the answer to demonstrate that.